# How do I access the text of button in the handler of OnClientClick. Equivalent of "this"?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I was assigning click handler using jquery like this, to toggle a button's functionality

```
$(function () {
$(".ButtonReorder").click(
        function () {
            //USER STARTS REORDERING - BUTTON CHANGES TO "SAVE" AND "CANCEL" BUTTON APPEARS
            if ($(this).attr("value") === "Reorder Images") {
                ...
            }
            //USER SUBMITS NEW ORDER - REORDERING GETS DISABLED
            else {
                ...
            }
        }
    );
```

Now, we are changing from html literal controls to ASP.Net control. It was posting back, which we don't want. I saw someone mention return false in the OnClientClick function. So instead of jQuery I tried assigning the JS function via OnClientClick, like this, but realized that this keyword now doesn't refer to the button. How do I refer to it?

//Code Behind

```
                Button reorderButton = new Button();
                reorderButton.CssClass = "ButtonReorder";
                reorderButton.Text = "Reorder Images";
                reorderButton.OnClientClick = "return reorderClick();";
```

//JS Code

```
function reorderClick() {
//USER STARTS REORDERING - BUTTON CHANGES TO "SAVE" AND "CANCEL" BUTTON APPEARS
if ($(this).attr("Text") === "Reorder Images") {
    $(this).attr("value", "Save New Order");    //change button to show "Save New Order" from "Reorder Images" 
     ...
     return false; //starting reorder, don't want to submit;
}
//USER SUBMITS NEW ORDER - REORDERING GETS DISABLED
else {
    $(this).attr("value", "Reorder Images");    //set button back to original "Reorder Images" from "Save New Order"
    ...
    return true; //done reordering, submit;
}
```

}

But this doesn't refer to button. Doesn't OnClientClick pass the object of action to the handler?
Is there a way to pass it?

Thanks,
Ozgur Ozturk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ye i think like this:

```
reorderButton.OnClientClick = "return reorderClick(this);";

function reorderClick(obj) {
//USER STARTS REORDERING - BUTTON CHANGES TO "SAVE" AND "CANCEL" BUTTON APPEARS
if ($(obj).attr("Text") === "Reorder Images") {
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Reyaner,
It goes into if statement now, but didn't update the buttons text.

The first line in if updates the value but it still shows old value in browser. Later in if statement, it errors for another reason, I tell the debugger to continue. I believe it should update the title regardless, right?

Comment: In debugger watch $(clickedButton).attr("value")
I see the new value added after running
$(clickedButton).attr("value", "Save New Order");

Answer (score 0):

try passing **this** as an argument

```
"return reorderClick(this);";

function reorderClick(elem) {
if ($(elem).attr("Text") === "Reorder Images") {
```